# Не отображается RecyclerView внутри DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

Добрый день есть список который нужно показывать в `RecylerView` который в  `DialogFragmente` , но recyclerView  не отображает элементы хотя по дебагеру все проходит

```
public class ChooseCardDialog  extends DialogFragment{
    private List<Card> cardList;
    private  RecyclerView cardListDialogRecycler;

    public static ChooseCardDialog getNewInstance(List<Card> cardList) {
        ChooseCardDialog chooseCardDialog = new ChooseCardDialog();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("cardList", (Serializable) cardList);
        chooseCardDialog.setArguments(bundle);
        return chooseCardDialog;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_card_list, container);
        cardListDialogRecycler=rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_dialog_card_list);
        cardListDialogRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        cardList= (List<Card>) getArguments().getSerializable("cardList");
        CardListAdapter cardListAdapter = new CardListAdapter(cardList,this.getActivity());
        cardListDialogRecycler.setAdapter(cardListAdapter);
        cardListDialogRecycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        cardListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

вот адаптер

```
public class CardListAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardListAdapter.CardViewHolder>{
private List<Card> cardList;
private Context context;

public CardListAdapter(List<Card> cardList, Context context) {
    this.cardList = cardList;
    this.context = context;
}

public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView cardNumber;
    public ImageView  cardType;
    public CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardNumber=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_card_last_number);
        cardType=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_card_type);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_list_layout, parent, false);
    CardViewHolder cardViewHolder= new CardViewHolder(itemView);
    return cardViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Card card = cardList.get(position);
    holder.cardNumber.setText(CardUtils.cutToTheLastCharacters(card.getMaskedPan()));
   // holder.cardType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mastercard ));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cardList.size();
}
```

}

вот разметка recycler -a

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Выберите карту для оплаты : "
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_dialog_card_list"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView19">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

а вот xml модели

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="306dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.529"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view_card_type"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mastercard"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.571" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="****"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_view_card_type"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="****"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView16"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="****"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView17"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_card_last_number"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="1234"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView18"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>




</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: xml в порядке? и что проходит по дебагеру? И вопросы к этой строчке: `holder.cardNumber.setText(CardUtils.cutToTheLastCharacters(card.getMaskedPan()));` :)

Comment: @Jarvis_J дебагер отрабатывает всю длину адаптера и передает в view holder  и возвращается  в return rootView тоесть у него все ок ниче не упало

Comment: а `CardUtils.cutToTheLastCharacters(card.getMaskedPan())`? Проверьте текст не отображается вообще или только такой

Comment: а вообще, есть вопросы и к xml... `height="24dp"` != `Bottom="8dp"+Top="8dp"+textSize="15dp"` `textSize` вообще лучше в `sp` задавать... Может быть проблема в абсолютных значениях, проверьте

Comment: адаптер рабочий стоит его просто во фрагменте вызвать все ок а во fragment dialog не отображается.

Comment: нет отметка работает во фрагменте почеиу она не  работает вр fragment dialog

Comment: обычно я пишу не `this.getActivity()`, а просто `getActivity()`... и другие предположения навскидку, при просмотре кода))

Comment: этот же кусок кода вне диалога работает у вас корректно? Посмотрите, приходит ли в адаптер нужный list